# How can I prevent Spring MVC from doing a redirect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to handle an AJAX request that updates an entity. I don't really need it to return anything. The problem is that Spring MVC insists on sending a redirect to the same URL (apparently doing its post-redirect-get thing), which the browser dutifully follows.

How can I have a Spring MVC controller method just complete and return something without sending a redirect? Searching on the web only leads to countrless discussions of how to do a redirect, not how to avoid one.

It's a PUT request to `http://localhost:9090/pex/api/testrun/f0a80b46-84b1-462a-af47-d1eadd779f59e` with these headers:

```
Host: localhost:9090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:9090/pex/api/testrun/f0a80b46-84b1-462a-af47-d1eadd779f59e/visualizations/common-api?slas=lp,internal,external
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic xxxx
```

The response has status code "302 Found", no body content and these headers:

```
Content-Language: "de"
Content-Length: "0"
Location: "http://localhost:9090/pex/api/testrun/f0a80b46-84b1-462a-af47-d1eadd779f59e"
Server: "Jetty(6.1.10)"
access-control-allow-origin: "*"
```

Here's the Server-side code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/testrun/{testrunId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Testrun updateOverview(@PathVariable("testrunId") final String testrunId, @RequestBody final String body) {
    return testrunService.updateOverview(testrunId, body);
}
```

Here's the Javascript code that makes the AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#update_name_form").submit(function (e) {
        update_testrun($("#name"));
        return false;
    });
}
function update_testrun(element) {
    var name = element.attr('name');
    var new_value = element.val().trim();
    var data = {};
    data[name] = new_value;
    $.ajax({url: config.urls.api.testrun + testrun.id,
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    testrun.overview[name] = new_value;
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: `@ResponseBody` doesn't send a redirect by default; something else is probably happening here.

Comment: using `@ResponseBoby` annotation method should only return a serialized `Testrun` object without redirecting. Which code are you using to make AJAX call?

Comment: Please add more details, like network console information with the redirect response. The code you've posted would not, by itself, cause a redirect.

Comment: @beerbajay: sure - but what could this "something else" be?

Comment: Some configuration would be nice.

Comment: Are you looking for anything in particular for your bounty, or not now that it is a human error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: a comprehensive and authoritative (i.e. with citation from the Spring MVC docs) list of what might cause a redirect, enabling a process of elimination, would be ideal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring MVC is built on top of the Servlet API. As such, any component that has access to the `HttpServletResponse` can theoretically use it to [`sendRedirect(String)`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) or set the response code manually. (I say *theoretically* because the response must not have yet been committed when those calls are made.)

Typically, in a Spring MVC application, a `@Controller` can receive the `HttpServletResponse` (or `ServletResponse`) in a `@RequestMapping` method as an [argument](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

A [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) receives it three times as part of the `DispatcherServlet`'s request handling lifecycle.

Any registered Servlet [`Filter`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/servlet/Filter.html) instances also have access to the `ServletResponse` before (and after) Spring's [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) since filters act before servlets.

Spring tries to hide all these dependencies to the Servlet API to make programming web server easier. It therefore provides other ways to cause a redirect. These mostly depend on the [supported handler method return types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types). More specifically, we care about `String`, `View`, `ModelAndView`, and `ResponseEntity`.

The following are all default cases:

When you return a `String`, Spring will use a [`ViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) to resolve a [`View`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html) based on the `String` value, which identifies the name of the view. Spring's [`UrlBasedViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html) will detect [a `redirect:` prefix](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) in `String` view names and consider it as an indication to send a redirect response. It will create a [`RedirectView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) (part of this is actually done in `ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler`, but `UrlBasedViewResolver` creates the `View`) which will be in charge of doing the redirect with the `HttpServletResponse`.

This is an implementation detail, but most of Spring's default `ViewResolver` classes do this.

With [`View`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html), you can simply create and return a `RedirectView` yourself. You can also implement your own `View` class that will do the same. Spring will use the appropriate [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) to handle it.

With `ModelAndView`, it's a mix of the two previous options since you can provide either a view name or a `View` itself.

With [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) it gets more interesting since you control the whole response. That is, you can set a status code, headers, body, everything. All you need to do is therefore set the status code to 302 and put a `Location` header with the URL to redirect to.

Finally, you have similar behavior in [`@ExceptionHandler` methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) (with similar return types) which you can also mix with [`@ResponseStatus`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) and modifying the headers manually.

These are all the basic cases, but since Spring MVC is almost completely customizable, there are other components to be aware of. These are [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html), `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`, [`HandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerAdapter.html), [`HandlerExceptionResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) and [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html), and more. Note that you'll rarely play with these and those that come with Spring pretty much do the whole job.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Or to write really great apps :)

Answer (score 3):

So,

I took your code and created an application with that, tried sending a PUT request using browser plugin POSTMAN and got a response but no redirection. See if this works.
I am attaching the complete classes, you can copy and directly use it in ur application.

Here are the network headers:

```
Remote Address:::1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/test/api/testrun/hello
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK

**Request Headers**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,pl;q=0.4
Authorization:Basic ZWFzeWwtbWFpbi1pbnQ6cHJnc3VzZXI=
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36

**Response Headers**
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Tue, 10 Jun 2014 10:58:50 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering
```

And here is the code:
**Configuration to boot up spring**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("production")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com", excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class) })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configureContentNegotiation(
            ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true)
                .parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() throws Exception {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/testrun/{testrunId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateOverview(@PathVariable("testrunId") final String testrunId) {
        System.out.println(testrunId);

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>test</display-name>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.WebConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring recommends using the post-redirect patterns but id does **not** do anything by default.
In my controllers I have to explicetely end the methods dealing with posts by `return "redirect:/url";`

I suspect the redirect to be done in the `testrunService.updateOverview(testrunId, body);` call.

Edit : in reality, nothing in `testrunService.updateOverview(testrunId, body);` could cause a redirect because of the `@ResponseBody` annotation. With code like that, only interceptors or filters could do a redirection.

Comment: Your suspicion is incorrect, but your insistence that the redirect is not done by default made me double-check stuff until I realized that my Maven launch configuration was simply still running an old version of the code... *groan*

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are right, I didn't pay enough attention to `@ResponseBody` annotation. I edited my post accordingly.