# Spring controller, why is the returned view ignored?

Tags: spring

So, say I have an existing, working page `Display Cashier`, which displays information about a cashier in a shop. Now, I add a button to this page that looks like:

```
<a href="handleGetManager.ctl?cashierId=${id}" class="btn btn-mini">Manager</a>
```

The request-mapping for this URL maps it (successfully) to a controller: `HandleGetManager`

the `HandleGetManager` controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class HandleGetManager{

    private employeeBO employeeBO; //BO handles all business logic

    //spring hooks
    public HandleGetManager(){} 
    public void setemployeeBo(employeeBO employeeBO){
    this.employeeBO = employeeBO;
    }

    //get controller 
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getManager(@RequestParam String cashierId){

    Long managerId = employeeBO.getManagerByCashierId(cashierId); 

    String redirectUrl = "/displayManager.ctl?managerId=" + managerId.toString();
    return redirectUrl;
    }

}
```

Here's what happens when I try it:

I hit the new button on the `Display Cashier` page, I expect the following to happen:

- The browser sends a get request to the indicated URL
- The spring request-mapping ensures that the flow of control is passed to this class.
- the `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)` piece ensures that this method is evoked
- The `@RequestParam String cashierId` instructs Spring to parse the URL and pass the cashierId value into this method as a parameter.
- The EmployeeBo has been injected into the controller via spring.
- The Business logic takes place, envoking the BO and the `managerId` var is populated with the correct value.
- The method returns the name of a different view, with a new managerId URL arg appended

Now, up until this point, everything goes to plan. What I expect to happen next is:

- the browsers is directed to that URL
- whereupon it will send a get request to *that* url,
- the whole process will start again in another controller, with a different URL and a different URL arg.

*instead* what happens is:

- this controller returns the name of a different view
- The browser is redirected to a half-right, half wrong URL: `handleGetManager.ctl?managerId=12345`
- The URL argument changes, but the name of the controller does not, despite my explicitly returning it
- I get an error

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something?

Comment: Depending on your `ViewResolver` you can prefix `redirectUrl` with `redirect:` to make the redirect happen.

Comment: Hi Bart, Thanks for your reply, could you explain the difference? What does the "redirect:" do? Isn't the view specified by the string returned?

Comment: You don't return a view from a controller. You typically return a view name that will be translated into a `View` implementation. When using a `UrlBasedViewResolver` prefixes like `redirect:` and `forward:` have a special meaning. In case of `redirect:` it will be translated into a `RedirectView` pointing to the value after the prefix.

Comment: Well... Like Sotirios Delimanolis said :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `UrlBasedViewResolver` in your MVC configuration, the `String` value you return is a View **name**. The `ViewResolver` will take that name and try to resolve a `View` for it.

What you seem to want to do is to have a 301 response with a redirect. With view names, you do that by specifying a `redirect:` prefix in your view name. It's described in the documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting).

Here's a question/answer explaining all the (default) ways you can perform a redirect:

- [How can I prevent Spring MVC from doing a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086207/how-can-i-prevent-spring-mvc-from-doing-a-redirect/24145240#24145240)

Comment: Hi Sotirios, Thanks very much for your answer! Is the Dev required to implement/configure the ViewResolver in Spring, or can it run as default out of the box?